# Windows Installer: can two different installer share the same componet

Tags: windows, wix, installation, wix3

I have two installers - one for 64-bit Windows and another for 32-bit Windows. The 32-bit installer installs 32-bit executable and DLls, while the 64-bit installer installs 64-bit exes and dlls as well as the 32-bit ones. The 32-bit components are shared by both installers.

Does Windows Installer explicitly allow this scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported. Just make sure that the 32-bit components have the same names and GUIDs in both installers. This way a reference count is used for them.